# Simple Azure retrieveEntity is not executed at all

Tags: node.js, azure

This very simple thing does not work for me even though I have practically copy + pasted the example code from here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node

It seems that tableService.retrieveEntity never fires at all? The context.log does not print anything. I get a status 200 with no body but this is because that is Azure's default.

It is the same problem if I write a query and use the queryEntities-method as well.

I write these things in the Azure Portal for simplicity's sake.

This is my code:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    var tableService = azure.createTableService('myTable', 'GoYVMvN+SXRJhzVERIYWFu6k0/DkZINIerS+YpwmQVy3ppPFJ+8bTavfisHJvsNbo5hjgpw40bWv8XXXXXXXXX==');

    tableService.retrieveEntity('myList', 'MyPartitionKey', '1', function(error, result, response) {

        context.log("retrieving...")

        if(!error){
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: "The entity was retrieved"
            }
        } else {
            context.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: "The entity was not retrieved"
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? My guess is that you're not awaiting the result where you call this function.

Comment: The above is my entire code. I call it via running the http request in the azure portal. If I switch retrieveEntity with insertEntity + parameters then everything works as expected and it inserts the entity as I want in the called table.

Comment: @Gurav Mantri, you where right. When I removed async this started working. Thank you for your time.